# Using the len() function in python I am somehow getting the wrong length

Tags: python-3.x

So I am learning to code and I am an absolute beginner here. Beginner as in I've been coding for maybe like 5 hours total. Not including the 4.5 hour video I watched at 1.5 times speed for my intro to python.

I am trying to make a hangman game and was messing around with it. I have a separate file full of words that the game randomly draws from, and then the user tries to guess it. My problem is that after selecting the "hidden_word" if I use len(hidden_word) and it gives me the wrong length of the word.

They are all single words, and in the text file there are no spaces before or after any of the words. Each word is on a new line, and every word selected has a length of 1 greater than it should be. For instance, the word Jinx, apparently has 5 letters.

The file is literally just this list, but 45 lines.

```
Awkward
Bagpipes
Banjo
Bungler
...
```

My code:

```
from random import randint

# open words file and choose a hidden word
dictionary = open("words.txt", "r")
words = dictionary.readlines()
hidden_word = words[randint(0, 45)]
dictionary.close()
print(hidden_word)
```

It always gives me a length of 1 longer than it should be.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Note the newline character `\n` counts as one.

Comment: `dictionary.readlines()` => `dictionary.read().splitlines()`

Comment: note that you can use `random.choice(words)` too

Answer (score 1):

As @jonrsharpe pointed out in the comments, the newline character `\n` counts as a character, and that newline character is included in each item of `.readlines()`.

To accurately get the length, you're going to want to strip the whitespace (spaces and newlines, etc.) before trying to find the length:

```
hidden_word = hidden_word.strip()
print(len(hidden_word))
```